# simple die roll application issue

Tags: javascript, html

I am learning javascript and I have written a short die roll app but it does not run when the button is clicked. I can't see where the problem is. Can somebody help me with this.

```
    <!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type=text/javascript>

        var face0= new Image() face0.src="d1.gif"
        var face1= new Image() face1.src="d2.gif"
        var face2= new Image() face2.src="d3.gif"
        var face3= new Image() face3.src="d4.gif"
        var face4= new Image() face4.src="d5.gif"
        var face5= new Image() face5.src="d6.gif"

        function rollDice(){
        var randomdice= Math.round(Math.random() *5)document.images["mydice"].src=eval("face" * randomdice+".src")
        }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <img src="d1.gif" name="mydice">
    <form>
    <input type="button" value="Roll" onclick="rollDice()">
    </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors (check the JS console)?

Comment: WTF is `Math.round(Math.random() *5)document.images["mydice"].src=eval("face" * randomdice+".src")` supposed to do? Fix your syntax errors, and do not use `eval` (but an array for your images).

Comment: @Bergi `eval` is perfectly fine in this situation. Although I do agree an array makes much more sense.

Comment: its a function that is supposed to randomly display the 6 images I have stored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please don't use `eval`. Instead do something like this:

```
var faces=[]
var numFaces=6;
for(var i=1;i<=numFaces;i++){
    var img=new Image();
    img.src='d'+i+'.gif';
    faces.push(img);
}
window.rollDice=function(){
    var randomdice= Math.floor(Math.random()*numFaces);
    document.images["mydice"].src=faces[randomdice].src;
}
```

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/fZY3u/

Comment: I would +1 this, but I'd hate to see what your code would be for a 100-sided die...

Comment: @Kolink I would love to see a 100-sided die

Comment: @Kolink Maybe I should change it to a for loop...

Comment: @Ian [Wish granted](http://unclesgames.com/images/products/N00388_big.jpg) - I was amazed when I saw this thing for real.

Comment: @Kolink Oh no! Haha I didn't expect there to be one for real

Comment: @Kolink My (revised) code for a 100-sided die complete with (404) image preloading: http://jsfiddle.net/jdwire/3JjHK/

Comment: If I was to get the value of the die which was rolled and display it, would I need to follow a different solution?? @jdwire.

Comment: @user1810449 Do you mean you want to display the text of the number rolled? If so, add 1 to the `randomDice` variable in the `rollDice` function, and that will be the number rolled. Use that to display the number rolled somewhere as text.

Comment: Yes display the text of the number rolled. Ok I shall try this Thanks.

Comment: So with in the roll dice function, add 1 to randomdice variable like so>> var randomdice= Math.floor(Math.random()*numFaces)+1;

Comment: @user1810449 Only do that if you don't want to display the image otherwise, it will cause null reference errors. If you still want display the image, just add one to the value when you display it: `element.innerHTML='You rolled a '+(randomdice+1);`

Comment: Oh okay, I have done it by adding the following code within the roll dice function and displayed it in a textbox on the form var results=randomdice+1;
 document.getElementById("res").value = results;
 <input type="text" name="result" id="res">

Answer (score 2):

Semicolons are not optional. The browser will try to insert them as best it can, but it can be wrong a lot of the time.

Additionally, ***use a @!#$ array***! That's what they're there for!

Try this:

```
(function() {
    var i, faces = [];
    for( i=0; i<6; i++) {
        (faces[i] = new Image()).src = "d"+(i+1)+".gif";
    }
    window.rollDice = function() {
        var side = Math.floor(Math.random()*6);
        document.getElementById('mydice').src = faces[side].src;
    }
})();

...

<img src="d1.gif" id="mydice" />
```

And remove the form. You are not submitting anything, so you don't need a form.

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain what I did wrong so I might rectify it?

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there - you just need `semi colons` between your statements, and you need to concatenate strings with '+', not '*'

**Edit**

As Kolink points out, `eval` [is dangerous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197769/when-is-javascripts-eval-not-evil).

You don't actually need to instantiate `Image()`s at all - given that you have 6 gifs for the sides of the die, all you need to do is change the `src` filename on your image, like so:

```
 function rollDice(){
     var randomdice= Math.round(Math.random() *5) + 1; // +1 since your gifs are 1-6
     document.images["mydice"].src = "d" + randomdice.toString() + ".gif";
 }
```

[Updated Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sLPCd/3/)

**Edit** Be aware of the caveats noted by the points below that this answer doesn't preload the images, which will have a performance hit the first time each dice face gif is triggered for the first time, before it is cached.

Comment: -1 for encouraging the horrific use of `eval`.

Comment: Well, I didn't explicitly discourage it, but OP seemed to have his mind set on `eval` already :)

Comment: I think Kolink's point is not that it's evil...it's perfectly fine in this situation, but it's being used as an attempt to replace an array, which isn't the best approach.

Comment: And instantiating `Image`s isn't necessary as you've pointed out, but it preloads them, so they are cached for faster loading later. Not that faster loading is necessary for a simple situation like this

Comment: Worst part is, you can even use `window['face'+randomdice]` and it's better than `eval`.

Comment: @Kolink Huh, didn't think of that. I guess that makes sense since everything's in the global scope. That's what makes your solution nice, nothing extra is exposed

Comment: This code is good, but it won't preload the images like the OP's code will.

Answer (score -1):

You missed semi-colons `;`

```
    var face0= new Image(); face0.src="d1.gif";
    var face1= new Image(); face1.src="d2.gif";
    var face2= new Image(); face2.src="d3.gif";
    var face3= new Image(); face3.src="d4.gif";
    var face4= new Image(); face4.src="d5.gif";
    var face5= new Image(); face5.src="d6.gif";

    function rollDice(){
       var randomdice= Math.round(Math.random() *5); 
       document.images["mydice"].src=eval("face" + randomdice+".src");
    }
```

Note: Always format your code neatly. Don't write all codes in one line, it will confuse you.

Comment: Thanks, Ive just add the semi colons but it still does not run...

Comment: -1 for not correcting the horrific misuse of `eval`.

Comment: @Kolink How is this a misuse?

Comment: The other problem is `eval("face" * randomdice+".src")` - it needs to be `eval("face"+randomdice+".src")` as someone else already pointed out

Comment: I didn't notice `eval` there. `eval` is not even required there.

Comment: If the code is refactored, then it isn't required, that's correct. But in its current state, the "*" character needs to be changed to a "+", was my point.

Comment: @Ian I changed it to `+`

Comment: @Kolink I mean, I definitely agree an array would be the better solution, but using `eval` isn't evil in this case. It's not like the user is `eval`ing user input or database-stored information. And it's only for 6 items. Nonetheless, it's better to teach the preferred method. These answers are solutions to the short-term problem, not the long-term

Comment: wOW this question engaged alot of interest, Id like to thank you guys and I will learn alot from this. :)